# concatenate key value pairs from python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, hashtable

I have a dictionary in python. The keys and the values are both strings. In fact the keys are some kind of flag (like `-f`) and the values are the options (e.g. an int like `20`). What I want to do is to create a string with all the keys and values. 
The dictionary could look something like this: 
`{'-f': 20, '-d': 30}` and what I would like is something like this:
`"-f 20 -d 30"`
I think this should be any easy task, but I couldn't find a solution until now...

Comment: Are the values strings or ints?

Comment: this can actually differ

Comment: Are you perhaps trying to produce command line arguments?

Comment: yes exactly. I didn't know of a better way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach using a list comprehension:

```
d = {'-f': 20, '-d': 30}
' '.join([i for k,v in d.items() for i in [k, str(v)]])
# '-f 20 -d 30'
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
out = []
for k,v in d.items():
    for i in [k, str(v)]:
        out.append(i)

' '.join(out)
# '-f 20 -d 30'
```

Comment: that' s pretty nice:) Thanks a lot!! Could maybe very briefly explain what this nesed list comprehension does. I tried to understand it, but can't wrap my head around it:(

Comment: Maybe a regular for loop helps you understand? @RobinKohrs :)

Comment: helped a lot:) Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

An attempt:

```
s = ''
for k, v in dct.items(): 
    s += k + ' ' + str(v) + ' '
    # remove the last character, an unnecessary space
    s = s[:-1]
```

Comment: You could edit this further so you don't need to lookup the value in the dict to get the value by using ... for k, v in dict.items(): k + " " + v + " "

Answer (score 1):

you could use `str.join` with [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions):

```
d = {'-f': 20, '-d': 30}

' '.join(str(e) for t in d.items() for e in t)
# '-f 20 -d 30'
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on yatu answer but with [f-strings](https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/) you could do :

```
d = {'-f': 20, '-d': 30}
' '.join([f"{k} {v}" for k,v in d.items()])`
# '-f 20 -d 30'
```